# Excel VBA - Interpret "N/A" Values

Tags: vba, types, excel

I am traversing a spreadsheet which contains a column of prices, in the form of `double` types. I am trying to locate a missing value which is shown on the spreadsheet as `"n/a"`, but it is not letting me interpret this as a `string` type.

The cell containing `"n/a"` seems to be an `integer` type; how can I read this?

Comment: When you hit upon a call with "n/a" what exactly do you want to do? Not sure I understand what you mean by 'how can I read this'? Or are you simply trying to check if the cell contains a missing value or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cell containing #N/A is retrieved by VBA as a variant containing an error code

In general its usually best to assign Excel cells to Variants because a cell can contain a number(double), logical, string or error and you cannot tell in advance what the cell wil contain.

Answer (score 12):

If all you want to do is to check for the error value then:

`Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(rngToCheck.Value)`

where `rngToCheck` is the cell which you want to check for the `#N/A` error value

(There's a list of the worksheet functions which can be called from Excel VBA [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221655%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

You could also examine `rngToCheck.Text` as this will contain the string "#N/A"

If instead, you want to read the formula in the cell which generated the `#N/A` then `rngToCheck.Formula` would do that

Comment: `rngToCheck.Text` was the solution for my instance of this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can prepare the spreadsheet you like to check as described below and evaluate the special cells containing the *IS Functions*, it is easy to check them for `True` or `False` in VBA. Alternatively, you can write your own VBA function as shown below.

---

There are **Excel functions** which check cells for special values, for example:

```
=ISNA(C1)
```

(assumed that C1 is the cell to check). This will return `True` if the cell is `#N/A`, otherwise `False`.

If you want to show whether a **range of cells** (say "`C1:C17`") has any cell containing `#N/A` or not, it might look sensible to use:

```
=if(ISNA(C1:C17); "There are #N/A's in one of the cells"; "")
```

Sadly, this is **not the case**, it will not work as expected. You can only evaluate a single cell.

However, you can do it **indirectly** using:

```
=if(COUNTIF(E1:E17;TRUE)>0; "There are #N/A's in one of the cells"; "")
```

assuming that each of the cells `E1` through `E17` contains the `ISNA` formulas for each cell to check:

```
=ISNA(C1)
=ISNA(C2)
...
=ISNA(C17)
```

You can hide column `E` by right-clicking on the column and selecting *Hide* in Excel's context menu so the user of your spreadsheet cannot see this column. They can still be accessed and evaluated, even if they are hidden.

---

In **VBA** you can pass a range object as `RANGE` parameter and evaluate the values individually by using a FOR loop:

```
Public Function checkCells(Rg As Range) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = False
    For Each r In Rg
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(r) Then
            result = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    checkCells = result
End Function
```

This function uses the IsNA() function internally. It must be placed inside a module, and can then be used inside a spreadsheet like:

```
=checkCells(A1:E5)
```

It returns `True`, if any cell is `#N/A`, otherwise `False`. You must save the workbook as macro-enabled workbook (extension `XLSM`), and ensure that macros are not disabled.

---

**Excel** provides more functions like the above:

```
ISERROR(), ISERR(), ISBLANK(), ISEVEN(), ISODD(), ISLOGICAL(), 
ISNONTEXT(), ISNUMBER(), ISREF(), ISTEXT(), ISPMT()
```

For example, `ISERR()` checks for all cell errors except `#N/A` and is useful to detect calculation errors.

All of these functions are described in the *built in help* of Excel (press F1 and then enter *"IS Functions"* as search text for an explanation). Some of them can be used inside VBA, some can only be used as a cell macro function.