# What VBA variable type to use when reading values from a cell in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624930/4765962) one should always use `Variant` when assigning values in a cell to a variable in the code. Is this correct? I seem to recall reading elsewhere that using `Variant` indiscriminately is not a good practice.

Comment: Unless you know exactly what type will be in the cell then `Variant` is the best method.  Also if you are trying to assign a range to an array the only way is Variant, unless you loop and put each in one at a time.  But the minute you try to load anything that does not fit the type it will cause the code to crash.  So Variant is the safest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read a cell value into any type you want, VBA will (try to) implicitly convert it to that type for you.

There are dozens of questions on this site involving run-time errors raised from reading cell values into a specific data type - perhaps you've seen this error message before?

> *Type mismatch*

That's the error you get when you try to read a cell containing an error value (e.g. `#REF!`) into **anything** other than a `Variant`.

So if you read a cell value into, say, a `Double`, everything will work fine *as long as you're reading something that VBA can coerce into that data type*. The problem is that, well, data is never 100% clean, worksheets *do* break down, users delete columns and break formulas, lookups fail and the person that wrote the formula didn't bother wrapping it with `IFERROR`, etc.

That's why you *read* cell values into a `Variant`.

That doesn't mean you *work* with a `Variant`.

```
Dim cellValue As Variant
cellValue = someRange.Value

If IsError(cellValue) Then Exit Sub 'bail out before we blow up

Dim workingValue As String
workingValue = CStr(cellValue)
```

By assigning to another data type, you effectively *cast* the `Variant` to that more specific type - here a `String`. And because you like explicit type conversions, you use VBA's conversion functions to make the conversion explicit - here `CStr`.

Now, in real code, you probably wouldn't even bother reading it into a `Variant` - you can use `IsError` to test the cell value:

```
If IsError(someRange.Value) Then Exit Sub 'bail out before we blow up

Dim cellValue As String
cellValue = someRange.Value ' or cellValue = CStr(someRange.Value)
```

The flipside here is that you're accessing the cell twice. Whether or not that's better that reading it into a `Variant` is for you to decide; performance-wise, it's usually best to avoid accessing ranges as much as possible though.

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know about type conversions. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) is the MSDN page for them if anyone is interested.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Mind telling me what's wrong with this answer so I can improve it? /edit: added a note about not *really* needing to read the cell value into a variable. Hope I'm a good mind reader.

Comment: *(+1) from my side.* Yet, maybe you want to add one more thing to your answer to make it possibly better: I don't think it has been made abundantly clear that a `variant` will (in the end) hold as many different variable types as is necessary (and `variant` is the only one offering that kind of variety). That means if `A1` contains nothing, `A2` contains a string, `B1` contains a date, and `B2` contains `=1/0` (resulting in an error) then the resulting array `arr = Range("A1:B2").Value2` will contain a string, a double, an error, and an `empty` as data types: `Debug.Print TypeName(arr(1, 1))`.

Comment: @Ralph thanks - I'll edit with a quote+link from the relevant docs.so topic when I get a chance.

Answer (score 5):

The value you get from a cell (which is a `Range`) is a `Variant` according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx):

> #### Range.Value Property (Excel)
>
> Returns or sets a **Variant** value that represents the value of the specified range.

Since a `Variant` can represent different data types, you could *loose* information if you would assign a cell's value to -- for instance -- a variable of type `String`.

The mere fact that there is data type information in a `Variant` already means you lose that type of information. If for instance the original type was numeric and you store it in a `String` variable, there is no way to know from that string value what the original data type was. You could also lose precision (on `Date` milliseconds for instance).

Furthermore, a `Variant` type value cannot always be cast to the data type of your variable, and so you could get a [*Type mismatch error*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx). In practice this often happens with the `Error` sub data type.

Only when you know beforehand what the data type is of a certain cell's value, it would be good to define your receiving variable in that data type.

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly answering your question, but thought I'd add this for reference anyway.

With native Excel functions you can usually provide either a range object or a value directly to a function. For example, you can either write `=AVERAGE(A1,A2,A3)` or `=AVERAGE(10,20,30)`. If you want to do something similar for any user defined functions, you will need to check the type of object passed to your function:

```
Function test(input As Variant)

Dim var As Variant
If TypeName(input) = "Range" Then
    var = input.Value
Else
    var = input
End If
```

You may also want to check for other objects if your function can accept them, but doing this will make your functions behave more like users expect them to.