# VBA: If statement in for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to get a mismatch error when trying to write an if statement in a for loop.

This is the piece of code where I get the error. Note, I only get the error when the IF condition is true.

```
Dim lastRow2 As Long
lastRow2 = Worksheets("csvFile").Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim r As Integer
For r = 3 To lastRow2
    If Worksheets("csvFile").Cells(r, 1) = "#N/A" Then
        rows(r).EntireRow.delete
    End If
Next r
```

So the goal is to delete the row where in the first cell `"#N/A"` is entered as a value.

Hope you guys can help and loads of thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Cells(r, 1).value`

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately doesn't work. Maybe good to add (will add to opening post too) is that I only get the error when the condition is true.

Comment: Have you tried double equals: `If Worksheets("csvFile").Cells(r, 1) == "#N/A" Then`

Comment: @kurdtpage That isn't how comparisons work in VBA.

Comment: I need to stop commenting before coffee... Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Interpret "N/A" Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624861/excel-vba-interpret-n-a-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this try:

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Worksheets("csvFile").Cells(r, 1)) Then
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. I'll test it a little more.

Comment: Don't know what I'm doing differently, but it deletes the row for me.

Comment: I was mistaken, it does so for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to see if a cell contains `#NA` you need to trap this type of error, which is a 2-Steps `If`.

Also, allways loop backwards when deleting `Rows`, use `For r = lastRow2 To 3 Step -1`.

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelNARows()

Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim CellVal As Variant

With Worksheets("csvFile") ' use with statement to qualify all Range, Rows and Cells object nested inside
    lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = lastRow2 To 3 Step -1 ' always loop backward when deleting rows
        ' trap #NA error section
        On Error Resume Next
        CellVal = .Cells(r, 1).Value
        On Error GoTo 0

        If IsError(CellVal) Then
            If CellVal = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then ' check if current error if xlErrNA (2042)
                .Rows(r).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: a faster way to delete multiple rows, is to delete all the rows at one shot, not one-by-one. You can achieve that by merging all the rows to be deleted in a `DelRng` (it's a `Range` object which is combined from all the rows that needs to be deleted).

***Code***

```
For r = lastRow2 To 3 Step -1
    ' trap #NA error section
    On Error Resume Next
    CellVal = .Cells(r, 1).Value
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim DelRng As Range ' define a new range to save all the rows to delete

    If IsError(CellVal) Then
        If CellVal = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then ' check if current error if xlErrNA (2042)
            If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(i))
            Else
                Set DelRng = .Rows(i)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next r

' delete the entire rows at once
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete
```