# Why appears the "type mismatch" error in if condition in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

Here is my code. *"For rowCycle = 4"* it's because I have double table header and indent from the border in one cell. The beginning of the required lines comes from the fourth line.

```
Sub ColumnsFind()

Dim ReqWorkbook1 As Workbook

Dim ReqWorkbook2 As Workbook

Set ReqWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ignatevaeg\Excel\VBA\Book1.xlsx")
Set ReqWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ignatevaeg\Excel\VBA\Book2.xlsx")

Dim rowCycle, secondCycle

secondCycle = 1

For rowCycle = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AT" & rowCycle).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AT" & rowCycle).Value <> "" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AT" & rowCycle).Value <> "#Н/Д" Then
    
        ReqWorkbook1.Sheets("Sales").Range("A" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("B" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook1.Sheets("Sales").Range("B" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook1.Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("D" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook1.Sheets("Sales").Range("D" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AT" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook1.Sheets("Sales").Range("E" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AU" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook1.Sheets("Sales").Range("F" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AV" & rowCycle).Value
        secondCycle = secondCycle + 1
    
    End If

Next rowCycle

For rowCycle = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AN" & rowCycle).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AN" & rowCycle).Value <> "" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AN" & rowCycle).Value <> "#Н/Д" Then
    
        ReqWorkbook2.Sheets("Sales").Range("A" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("B" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook2.Sheets("Sales").Range("B" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook2.Sheets("Sales").Range("C" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("D" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook2.Sheets("Sales").Range("D" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AN" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook2.Sheets("Sales").Range("E" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AO" & rowCycle).Value
        ReqWorkbook2.Sheets("Sales").Range("F" & secondCycle).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AP" & rowCycle).Value
        secondCycle = secondCycle + 1
    
    End If

Next rowCycle

End Sub
```

I tried this and got the "Type mismatch error" with the line 16 (**If condition**)

I don't know why, but when I decided to debug in "Watches" I see:
[image]

Why it is so, who knows?

Comment: Usually if cell contains formula error codes such as `#N/A` then VBA throws this error. I'd begin with checking the content of `Range("AT" & rowCycle)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624861/excel-vba-interpret-n-a-values

Comment: Welcome fierna! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your next badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You are checking the format code against "dd-mm-yyy". That is only **three digits** for the year. The format string might also include other characters, like for my setting: "yyyy-mm-dd;@". Therefore you need to be careful when checking for equality. I don't quite understand why you even feel that you need to check the set format.

Comment: I've already changed the format to "m/d/yyyy", the code is about to working good, but there is another problem with pasting in only one workbook instead of two. And now i'm working on it.

Comment: Should you not reset `secondCycle` to 1 for `ReqWorkbook2` in second loop ?

Answer (score 2):

A cell with the value `#N/A` will throw an exception when you try to match it with a literal string. There's three ways you can check for an exception.

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AT" & rowCycle)
    TypeName(.Value) =  "Error"
    .Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    IsError(.Value)
End With
```

You'll also need to test this *before* you try your other conditions.

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("AT" & rowCycle)
    If Not .Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        If .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy" And .Value <> "" Then
            ...
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Comment: `TypeName` check is weak (missing an "if" here), there's an `IsError` function that returns `True` given a `Variant/Error` value.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Updated for `IsError`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Handling Dates

- In a nutshell, if you're testing a cell for a date, use the `IsDate` function i.e. if it's a date, it cannot be empty, blank, or an error, or...
- Usually, you would want to open one workbook at a time, process it, save it (or not), and close it i.e. having the same code for both workbooks inside another outer loop. In this case, this is achieved by introducing three arrays at the beginning of the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportData()

    Dim dNames(): dNames = Array("Book1.xlsx", "Book2.xlsx")
    Dim sDateCols(): sDateCols = Array("AT", "AN")
    Dim sCols(): sCols = Array("AT:AC", "AN:AP")

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sales")
    Dim srg1 As Range: Set srg1 = sws.Columns("B:D")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook, dws As Worksheet, drg As Range
    Dim srg2 As Range, sr As Long, n As Long, sdCol As String
    
    For n = LBound(dNames) To UBound(dNames)
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ignatevaeg\Excel\VBA\" & dNames(n))
        Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Sales")
        Set drg = dws.Range("A1:C1")
        Set srg2 = sws.Columns(sCols)
        sdCol = sDateCols(n)
        For sr = 4 To slRow
            If IsDate(sws.Cells(sr, sdCol).Value) Then
                drg.Value = srg1.Rows(sr).Value
                drg.Offset(, 3).Value = srg2.Rows(sr).Value
                Set drg = drg.Offset(1)
            End If
        Next sr
        'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next n
 
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```